# Oracle SYSDATE format Change

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to change a format of Oracle SYSDATE so that it uses a specific format when running a PL/SQL procedure. This format is really unnecessary but I am update an old table and need to maintain this format due to some integrations. My problem is I am not able to replicate the format.
The format needed is: `15/MAR/17 09:31:08.000000000`

Currently the below is the closest I can get, I am not sure how to change `MM` to display MAR instead of 03.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS.SSSSSSSSS')
FROM DUAL;
```

Thanks a mill in advance

Comment: A `date` column has no format. You don't need to format your `date` values. Not in SQL and not in PL/SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. True, but what he is saying is that he needs to format the column results in order to match old data.

Comment: Was Google broken?  Formatting all there in the documentation.
 https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MON will display Month instead of numeric.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'DD/MON/YY HH24:MI:SS."000000000"')
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: yeah sorry, I fixed it, I just copied his text and pasted to fix MON :)

Answer (score 3):

To convert to text in the format you want (not that you should need to unless the DB design is awful).

```
substr(to_char(systimestamp,'DD/MON/YY HH24:MI:SS.FF')  || '000000000', 1, 28)
```

or

```
to_char(sysdate,'DD/MON/YY HH24:MI:SS')  || '.000000000'
```

Details on the format mask can be found [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php).

Note: sysdate does not return the fraction of a second, so if this is required, use systimestamp

Answer (score 2):

`SYSDATE` is of `DATE` type, which does not support fractional seconds, so you either need to concatenate `.000000000` with the formatted date:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         SYSDATE,
         'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) || '.000000000'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Or you need to `CAST` the `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         CAST( SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP ),
         'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS.FF9'
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: Or use systimestamp?

Comment: `CAST( SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP )` does not provide fractional seconds either, it would be the same as concatenating fixed string. Use `SYSTIMESTAMP`, `LOCALTIMESTAMP` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I am not trying to get the value for the fractional seconds (yes, `SYSTIMESTAMP` would do that) but to answer the OP's question (using `SYSDATE` as they specified) and get the string in the format that they wanted.